# Why aren't I required to wrap a checked exception with try, catch here?

Tags: java, exception, lambda

I use lambda expressions in the following code but even though the method throws a checked exception Eclipse doesn't require that I wrap the call with try, catch blocks. Why?

```
package lambda;

//Throw an exception from a lambda expression. 

interface DoubleNumericArrayFunc {
    double func(double[] n) throws EmptyArrayException;
}

class EmptyArrayException extends Exception { // Checked exception
}

public class LambdaExceptionDemo {

    public static void main(String args[]) throws EmptyArrayException {

        DoubleNumericArrayFunc average = (n) -> {
            if (true)
                throw new EmptyArrayException();
            return 1;
        };


        // Why try catch isn't required here?
        System.out.println("The average is " + average.func(new double[0]));
    }

}
```

Comment: because the main method is declared to throw it

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
public static void main(String args[]) throws EmptyArrayException {
```

Because you have a `throws` clause on `main()`. The exception is allowed to propagate, so catching it isn't required. Delete the `throws` and you'll be required to add a try/catch.